# What is the most time effiencent way to gain golden basic cards

Tags: hearthstone

I like gaining the golden cards that you earn from leveling up you heroes. I find that the closer I get to obtaining the next gold card, the more I want to just get that card rather than just playing against other players.

My understanding is that you earn by playing cards, destroying enemy minions, and winning games. You get less by playing in solo content, but you can more easily win the game and you can also play specifically to win fast or play all of your cards.

What I have been doing lately is play against Razorgore in Normal mode. I will play through my entire hand. He spawns new minions each turn so I have plenty to destroy and its pretty easy so I win unless I do something stupid or get a terrible opening hand.

Does anyone have any other ideas that they use to level up their heroes?

The "duplicate" question does indeed ask the same basic thing, however that was asked over 1 year ago. Hearthstone has added 2 adventure modes that were not taken into consideration at the time of that question. It is possible that it's answer is still correct, but no one has shown that to be true just used anecdotal evidence.

Comment: Don't you earn golden cards by leveling up your heroes? If that's the case, isn't playing against other players the most efficient way to level up?

Comment: you're correct on both counts

Comment: If answers to the old question are out of date, they should be updated.  A new question asking the same thing is not needed.  If you want to bring attention to the old question, you can use a bounty to do so.